# Git bash under windows

Tags: windows, git, bash, shell

I am getting crazy, while trying to write a companion script to help developers in my team to look up for changes in master branch.

My goal is to create a bahs/sh script to seek for **ALL** git repos on the developer machine, check if they were related to a certain client and them, aply some automatic updating to master branch **and alerting the dev**, that he should be aware of those changes when packaging their work for deployment.

Here's what I got so far:

```
find /c -type d -name .git -exec cygpath -U {} \; 2>/dev/null | sed 's@ @\\\\ @g' | while read eachGit
do
    cd \""$eachGit"/..\";  ##This line is failing
    pwd;
    for eachBranch in $(git branch --no-merged master)
    do
        #do some stuff for each Branch (which already works if I cd manually)
    done;
done;
```

When I tryed to do that `cd` command, it says:

```
bash: cd: "/c/Users/MyUser/.SomeSw/subDir/.git/..": No such file or directory
~
bash: cd: "/c/Users/MyUser/my\ repo\ folder/some\ project/.git/..": No such file or directory
~
```

If I copy the directory from the error message and try to cd to it, it works perfectly

And I am running it from a normal git bash although my plan is to run it from windows task scheduler as soon as it became ready to go

Comment: This has little to do with Windows or Git, and a lot to do with how shells interpret things you enter. Using a literal backslash-double-quote sequence tells the shell to include that double-quote character as part of the path name. It's *not* actually part of the path name. If you cut and paste the error message, it no longer has a backslash, and the *un-backslashed* double-quote means "allow spaces and certain other meta-characters in this, up to the closing quote, then strip off the quotes".

Comment: Hence, what you want is not `cd \""$eachGit"/..\"` but rather `cd "${eachGit}/.."`.  Here the quotes protect against spaces as before, but then get removed once the space-protecting is done. The braces around `eachGit` are not strictly necessary but make it clear that `$` should expand a variable named `eachGit`, not one named `eachGit/..`.  The `/..` part then gets included in what is passed to `cd` once the quotes are removed.

Comment: There are probably more refinements you can make, such as using `while read -r ...` to avoid needing to fiddle with spaces and backslashes (i.e., you should no longer need `sed` at all). I am not sure what `cygpath` does with path names though.

Comment: Great suggestions @torek, in fact I was trying a lot of combinations and already used `{}` braces, double quotes, but somewhat they didn't worked. Following your instructions, I removed the sed from my find and used `cd "${eachGit}/.."` and now the code works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @torek, I was misunderstanding how to quote variables.

The following cod works

```
find /c -type d -name .git -exec cygpath -U {} \; 2>/dev/null | while read eachGit
do
    cd "${eachGit}/..";  ##This line is failing
    pwd;
    for eachBranch in $(git branch --no-merged master)
    do
        #do some stuff for each Branch (which already works if I cd manually)
    done;
done;
```

I am pretty sure that I used something closely related to this before, but somewhat I got a wrong direction.